# data-toggle title reset not resetting text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am setting a tooltip on a div as follows; (I'm not sure why I'm doing it this way frankly but I saw a snippet that used this and it works the way I like it)

```
 <div id="termsandconditions" class="col-xs-6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Agree to the terms to enable the form">
        <a href="#modal-terms" data-toggle="modal" class="register-terms">Terms</a>
        <label class="switch switch-primary" >
            <input type="checkbox" id="register-terms" name="register-terms">
            <span></span>
        </label>
 </div>
```

***Update***
This produces a styled modal tooltip popup, I want to change the text within it on click event.
I suspect my inability to change the text has to do with the data-toggle attribute.
Using the prop or attr changes the tooltip, but not the title text in the modal tooltip popup that's set from data-toggle.

The following actually ADD a tooltip , but dont change the text in the original tooltip pop up

```
  $("#termsandconditions").dialog("option", "title", "De-selecting terms will disable the form");
  $('#termsandconditions').prop('title', 'De-selecting terms will disable the form');
```

Comment: .prop() works see http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/mFn54/

Comment: yes, it works in your fiddle, and it should, but its not working on my page. Something must be overriding it

Comment: Are you using any plugins that render your tooltips?

Comment: @dinotom, Problem must be somewhere else. You need to provide more innformation. As of now problem is not-repro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#termsandconditions').attr('data-original-title', 'De-selecting terms will disable the form');
```

Comment: @khriskooper... nice work. How did you find this? Are there docs somewhere I can peruse?

Comment: It looks like you're using bootstrap, which has it's own fancy way of rendering tooltips, and messes around with your HTML as a result. I always find the best way to see what exactly is going on is to search and debug the HTML in your browser. I couldn't find any documentation on the Bootstrap website for this, but there are a couple of examples of using it online. Just search for "dynamically change tooltip title in bootstrap" in Google.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#termsandconditions').attr('title', 'De-selecting terms will disable the form');
```

Comment: Using attr is the same as the prop example, prop is standard now for 1.6 or higher, and does not work either however. It would on a normal title attribute but I suspect the data-toggle is whats keeping that from working